# Altium Designer: Is it possible to detect PCB track router over cut in GND plane using DRC?

Tags: pcb-design, altium, signal-integrity, design-rules

It is essential that high speed tracks have continuos ground plane with no cuts. This is essential to ensure signal integrity. That being said, can Altium designer use some sort of user defined design rules to check if a PCB track is being routed over cuts in the GND plane or too close to cuts or edge of the plane?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend looking into the "Return Path" rule, located under the "High Speed" heading. I think this is what you are looking for. This rule will let you know if your trace leaves its reference plane, such as crossing over a split.

[image]